# Unable to delete Qlik Sense pivot table dimension column

Tags: qliksense

I have a Qlik Sense pivot table dimension column that is missing the arrow on the right side.  As such, I'm unable to delete it.  Also, this column is titled "Values" and I have no such column in the data set.  Is this a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is supposed to be there.  Please see this link on the QlikSense Forum: [Unable to delete Qlik Sense pivot table dimension column][1]


  [1]: https://community.qlik.com/t5/New-to-Qlik-Sense/Unable-to-delete-Qlik-Sense-pivot-table-dimension-column/m-p/1579693/highlight/false#M135422

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is probably expression/measure. I am including gif how you delete it (right click on dimension/meassure in edit mode) but I am not sure is it your problem (you can share more data screenshot, data model, dimensions/expressions or even qvf file):

[image]

UPDATED:

From your screenshot it seems that it is column in pivot table not dimension. Please try to move it to dimension as on gif below (in view mode). If not help you can try to change temporary table to normal straight Table. If not help delete and recreate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hubert.  No, sorry, it's a dimension column, not an expression/measure.  Right-clicking doesn't work on that Dimension, but it does on others.  I've attached a screen shot in my original post for clarity.